# String.Len() error

Tags: excel, vba

I am having difficulty finding the length of this string. Looking up examples of this but it looks correct.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO!  When posting code, while a screenshot is better than nothing, instead would you mind posting the actual code (putting it in code tags, the {} icon), and then you can add a line after saying you get an error, and what that error is.  That way, we can easily copy the code and try it on our end.

Comment: I second everything that @BruceWayne said.  Please post code as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

strComp is a function of VB, so you cant assign to it.  Use strComplete or something else.

Comment: To piggy back off of this, it's not recommended to use `Range` or `Cells` as a variable name too, for the same reason.  (OP didn't do this, but it's something beginners to VB understandably do often).

Comment: strComp is a function, not a keyword, thus the reason for the missing "(" error.